# Multi-Line Comments in CosmosDB SQL

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am very experienced with T-SQL (SQL Server). Recently I've been doing some work in CosmosDB SQL. It is obviously different in SO many ways from good ol' T-SQL. So here's a question:

How do we do **multi-line comments** in CosmosDB SQL? The SQL Server way `/* */` doesn't seem to work:

> Gateway Failed to Retrieve Query Plan: Message: {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":231,"end":232},"code":"SC1001","message":"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near '*'."}]}
> ActivityId: dcd0e077-34a1-4cc5-92dc-e97130fc4523, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0

Anyone? Thank you!

Comment: Why send comments with the query?

Comment: Can't you just put the comments in the code outside of the sql query string?

Comment: I think it's more important to focus on other things than study why cosmosdb sql can't support multi-line comments. At least I haven't found and docs on it. Do you have any other problems? And as Mark said why not putting your comments in the code?

Comment: Same issue in the [online demo](https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo): `--` works, `/*...*/` does not. Could be MS deemed it unimportant for a first version. Makes me wonder if the SQL API of Cosmos DB is a mature product. Anybody found any formal syntax description of Cosmos DB's SQL dialect?

Comment: @RuudHelderman - Why are you connecting "lack of multi-line comments" with "wonder if the SQL API is a mature product?" The SQL API works as presented. It's in a GA service (and has been available in GA for *years*). The SQL API query language receives updates as features are added or enhanced. It helps nobody, posting speculations like that. Fortunately, there's an avenue for you to suggest new features: UserVoice. Just note that Stack Overflow is not an Azure tech support site; it's a generic programming Q&A site. This isn't the place for deep-diving into why something is the way it is.

Comment: @DavidMakogon If you are genuinely interested in my opinion about the chasm between GA and maturity in the software industry, please meet me in chat. If you'd like to help OP, maybe you know of some reliable (formal) syntax description of the (apparently not fully standards-compliant) SQL dialect recognized by Cosmos DB. That's the least one should expect from mature software: documentation.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, folks. It sounds like this product isn't quite mature yet (not sure why user @Tiny-Wa and David Makogon seem defensive). So I'll abandon the search and just stick with single-line comments. I just have to keep reminding myself that CosmosDB is not an RDBMS, and is not quite mature in developer-friendliness, yet.

Answer (score 2):

There is no multi-line comments in Cosmos DB by now. You can only use `--` to do single-line comment as Ruud Helderman said. You can give feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) to progress this feature.